# Instr method in Javascript XPages

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs

Which method i can use in ServerSide Javascript instead of **Instr** method in LotusScript

Regards
Cumhur Ata

Comment: Opinion based questions are not allowed... Try something, let me know what you have tried

Comment: @Ajay really? Do you know what Cumhur is talking about?

Comment: @Ajay I would like to use the same method in SSJS but I could not find the method. I have searched and I couldn't. That is why I asked here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use

```
yourString.indexOf(yourSubstring)
```

It returns a value >= 0 if yourSubstring is part of yourString.
It is the position of yourSubstring in yourString starting with 0.
This is different to LotusScript's `InStr` which starts with 1.

Comment: Thank you so much. 
This is what exactly i am looking for.